# What traits do the Dwemer have in Elder Scrolls' lore?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-series

I'd like to know what traits the Dwemer have in terms of character creation on the ES games. For example, Wood Elves are good at archery. Is it known what the Dwemer were good at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dwemer have never been (officially) playable and in the entire series we have only encountered [one](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Yagrum_Bagarn) live Dwemer (and he was suffering from a crippling disease). There are thus no official sources to cite regarding what they would have been good at and what perks they would have imparted from a gameplay perspective.

However, there is a fair bit of lore about them, most of which serves to underscore the fact that they were *excellent* craftspeople and engineers, both of the physical and of the arcane.

From the [UESP wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Dwemer):

> > The Dwemer appear to have been a highly technologically advanced and particularly dogmatic race. Others races have still not cracked the secret behind their metal.

Their creations have survived for hundreds of years after their race vanished, some of them completely intact and functional. Their use of steam and geothermal power has not been widely reproduced in the rest of Tamriel, even at the time of Skyrim, which is (iirc) the most-recent era of Tamriel we've seen so far.

In addition to powering devices through mechanical means, they were also very adept at magical artifice (nearly all of their constructs, the guardians and spider-droids, appear to derive their power from soul gems or similar magical devices).

We can *theorize*, then, that they would be highly intelligent and proficient with magic, and that from a gameplay perspective one might see boosts to skills that dealt with passive magical abilities and construction skills. That is, they'd probably be good at enchanting and smithing and the like, not necessarily destruction, illusion or conjuration magic.

Comment: Thanks that's great. Is it know whether they would have a crafting advantage in game if they were playable?

Comment: @CJF No, it's not known since they are not playable. Perhaps there is a mod that would make them playable, but that mod would not be canon.

Comment: It is not, as they have never *been* playable. It's probably reasonable to assume as much (it certainly seems to *me* that it would fit with what we know of them from lore) but until the race is made playable by Bethesda the decision is in the hands of their designers.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I agree with Josh, that it is fair to assume that they would probably have a crafting advantage if they were implemented into the game.